# Is there a way to pass Parameters to child script from a text file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

Parent file: test.bat

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in (links.txt) do (
echo opening %%a
call  %%a
)
PAUSE
```

Text file: links.txt

```
Chrome.bat A
```

Child file: Chrome.bat

```
@echo off
echo %1
start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

The problem is Chrome.bat is not taking the parameter from links.txt (i.e "A").
Echo statement in Chrome.bat is displaying "Echo is off" rather than displaying "A". Can anyone provide solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a...
```

If you don't specify a delimiter, only the first token in the line is assigned to `%%a`. The default tokens include <kbd>Space</kbd>

See `for /?|more` from the prompt for details.

Comment: Hi , it worked for the above set of code. But its not working for this   `@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set /A "INDEX=0"
for /f "delims=" %%J in (links.txt) do (    
 echo %%J
 call set "$BATCH[%%INDEX%%]=%%J"
 set /A "INDEX+=1"
)`  (Application is not launching)

Comment: "not working" provides no information about what the problem is. It's not possible to see where your linebreaks are. In your code, you are merely `echo` ing the line read from the file. If you wish to execute it, you would need `call %%J` on a single line within the block delimited by the parentheses.

Comment: LB is line break `@echo off` LB `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion` LB `set /A "INDEX=0"` LB `for /f "delims=" %%J in (links.txt) do ( ` LB `call set "$BATCH[%%INDEX%%]=%%J"` LB `set /A "INDEX+=1"` LB `)` **Application is not launching.** I want to store the line read from file in an array so that i can generate a log file to write the exit code.

Comment: The only instructions within your `do` clause are to set `$BATCH[x]` and increment the index. To execute your application, you'd need to include `call %%J` as well.